# OnePlus One (CM 13.1.2) persisting boot loop

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, rom-flashing, boot-loop

My OnePlus One phone got stuck in a boot loop over night without, as far as I know, a specific reason to do so (no new update was installed). Before this it was running perfectly fine. The phone was running the stock CM.

The phone boots and shows the Cyanogen Mod Ready logo and then restarts (Android version 6.0.1, Cyanogen version 13.1.2).

I tried numerous things so far
Booting in safe mode, wiping the caches and a factory reset (as suggested on the [boot loop info page](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info)) all did not solve the problem.

Using ADB sideload to push and flash a zip of the ROM from the computer did not work. Yet no error was returned.

Furthermore, flashing the ROM with fastboot, as described here:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-one/general/guides-bacon-timmaaas-how-to-guides-t2839471 did not resolve the boot loop. Also here, no errors were returned when flashing the individual files.

I'm not sure what other options I could still explore.

Comment: The phone was plugged in when it happened?

Comment: The phone was at the moment charging through the power outlet.

Comment: So this leads me to think that there is something with the eMMC. I think it might be a hardware problem due to short-circuit

Comment: I was already suspecting a hardware issue, but afaik there is no way to check it. Also, if it would be the eMMC shouldn't the flashing return an error when I overwrite a file?
Thank you for your help so far

Comment: You're welcome. Since I'm not good in hardwares, I can't tell you exactly what is causing the issue. But let's return on software side, did you flash the Cyanogen OS Fastboot Images as described in the link you provided?

Comment: Yes, I did it in the same order and for all of the files they mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting OnePlus they set up a remote session.
During this session they also flashed the phone using their own files.
This, however, did not solve the problem.

The phone was still under waranty so they arranged it to be send for repair.
They found the motherboard to be faulty, which has been replaced and the phone works perfectly fine again.